# QGIS 2.18 Time Manager Plugin GPS movement map

Tags: qgis

I am trying to display the movement of vehicles that have GPS trackers on them in QGIS. I have a CSV file of the data that looks like so:
[Vehicle points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgVWx.jpg)

I import the CSV file into QGIS saved as a SHP and put in the necessary information into the Time Manager plugin in QGIS, but when I hit the play botton on the Time Manager all my points just disappear even though it shows it as playing through.

I've checked my date formats and they are correct as QGIS should take them as: yyyy/m/d HH:mm:ss

Any ideas or advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, there was a start lat and long and an end lat and long for each point. I had to set the end lat and long in the start lat and long for the next proceeding point for the a particular points vehicle ID. Doing this allowed me to track a vehicles movement.